# How to check changes in column values?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

I need to try to check some device IDs for work. These are values (15 characters, random string of numbers+letters) that mostly remain constant for users. However, every now and then these deviceIDs will change. And I'm trying to detect when they do change. Is there a way to write this kind of a dynamic query with SQL? Say, perhaps with a CASE statement?

| user | device | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23127dssds1272d | 10-11 |
| 1 | 23127dssds1272d | 10-11 |
| 1 | 23127dssds1272d | 10-12 |
| 1 | 23127dssds1272d | 10-12 |
| 1 | 04623jqdnq3000x | 10-12 |

Answer (score 1):

Count distinct device by id having count > 1?

Comment: ah, you know that could work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where true 
qualify device != lag(device, 1, '') over(partition by user order by date)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see here - at `10-11` first 'change, assignment' happened for user=1 ; and then on `10-12` he device changed